# How to make Vim start at the end of a template?

Tags: autocmd, startup

I have skeleton template files for various filetypes, and when I create a new file based on these templates, the cursor always starts at the top of the file. It would be more convenient if it started at the bottom.

Can I use a `ftplugin` or an `autocmd` to change the cursor's initial position?

Comment: Could give us more indication about your template files? Which autocmd trigger them such that we can propose you ways to ammend these commands?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @romainl I tried looking in the manual.

Comment: I don't know what `autocmd` is, but doesn't `vi +:$ file.txt` do what you want, very straightforwardly?

Comment: @NormanGray That works with existing files, but my question regards new files which start with a skeleton template. For example, you could start a bash script with the hashbang already present. https://vimtricks.com/p/vim-file-templates/

Comment: @paradroid ah, I see – that makes more sense!  I failed to register that in the question.  I didn't know about templates (so I've learned something), but I tend to use vi rather than vim.

Comment: @NormanGray you are probably using some version of Vim even though you might not know it. Most OS's provide an alias or symlink. Calling `:version` will tell you.

Comment: @Friedrich Sometimes, yes, but most of the time `vi` is actually `nvi` (version 2.2.0 is what's currently on FreeBSD).  Which is why, on platforms where `vi` is actually Vim, I have it aliased to `vi -C`, to avoid confusing myself.  That, or `ed`, of course...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you associate a template to a file extension using the following `autocmd`:

```vimscript
autocmd! BufNewFile *.foo 0r ~/vimfiles/template/template.foo
```

The `autocmd` import the `~/vimfiles/template/template.foo` when you create a new buffer that matches the `*.foo` pattern.

Then you could amend it using like:

```vimscript
autocmd! BufNewFile *.foo 0r ~/vimfiles/template/template.foo | $
```

Where the `:$` command moves the cursor at the end of the buffer.

Comment: Great, thanks. I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: Thank for the feedback :-)